# How to handle newlines in Javascript? (from PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, html, newline

I have code like this:

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var out="'.$txt.'";';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

Where $txt is a PHP variable that can contain newlines like this:

```
line1
 line2 hello world
```

Which would end up like this:

```
var out="line1
 line2 hello world";
```

Which will cause a Javascript error, of course.

What is the best way to handle this? The out variable will be used in a HTML textarea, so I don't think it can be parsed into `<br>`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
$txt = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r" ), array( "\\n", "\\r" ), $txt );
```

should replace newlines. ***Don't do it this way***.

**This is a naïve implementation of string escaping for JavaScript**. As you're *actually* trying to format a string for use in JavaScript, a much better solution would be to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$txt = json_encode($txt);
echo "<script>var out={$txt};</script>";
```

`json_encode` will correctly escape special characters in strings, such as quotes, tabs, form feeds, and other special unicode characters. It will also perform all the correct escaping for converting objects, arrays, numbers, and booleans.

Comment: textarea doesn't parse \n though, it's showing up as "\n" in the actual textarea.

Comment: are you triple escaping `\n`? In JavaScript `"\n"` will be a newline, but if you pass it `"\\n"` you'll get `\n` as output. Check your page source and see what the JavaScript code is coming out as.

Comment: Your question was how to handle it for Javascript.  Don't run str_replace on it if you're putting it into a textarea.

Comment: Textarea newline is a whole other issue, cant do it in placeholder for textarea without major hacks

Comment: @dirt, what do you mean by that? Do you mean you want the placeholder attribute of a textarea to span multiple lines?

Comment: Just letting everyone like @Zeno know that the textarea placeholder attribute does not support new lines at all, you can do it with value though.

Comment: So easy if you know it :)

Answer (score 4):

you can add a `\` at the end of a line to create a multi line String

```
var out="line1 \
 line2 hello world";
```

Comment: Something like this? $txt = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r" ), array( "\n", "\r\\" ), $txt );

Comment: Note the use of double (") not single (') quotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most of these don't work for me.
Normally, I'd use json_encode like

```
    <?php
        $MyVar = json_encode($MyVar);
    ?>
    <javascript language='javascript'>
        MyVar = <?php echo $MyVar; ?>
```

But for a quick fix you can just break a line like this:
Pay attention to the double quotes.

```
    <?php
    $MyVar = "line one here
              then line two here


              finally line five here";

    //** OR

    $MyVar = $MyVarA . 
    "

    " 
    . $MyVarB;

    ?>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <javascript language='javascript'>
    Myvar = "<?php echo $MyVar; ?>";
```

. . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` to convert line breaks into a different character (in this case, perhaps a space, but it depends how you want the output to show up)

```
$out = str_replace("\n", '\n', $in);
```

Comment: don't forget those pesky carriage returns. I nearly did.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked well.

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $txt = "line1 \\n line2 hello world";
    echo 'var out="'.$txt.'";';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

I am using PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = str_replace( "\\n", "\\\\\\n", $content );
```

Result:

```
var a = "Hello \
World"
```