# Dynamic loop variable in JavaScript with PHP elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, for-loop, imagemapster

I'm using a jquery plugin called [imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) to create a map with mysql / php content and values.

There are 120+ defined areas on the map and I'd like to use a loop to write the code for each pop up tooltip. Although I can create a loop in JavaScript and replace plain text I'm not having any luck including the JavaScript variables (i) inside the PHP elements.

The code I'm trying to replace is below. I'd like every instance of the number (1,2 and 3) to be generated by the loop. Is it possible to mix JavaScript and PHP like this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{

$('#shape1').mapster({
showToolTip: true,
toolTipContainer: '<div class="map_popup"></div>',
    fill : true, 
  areas:  [
          {                
           key: "1", 
           toolTip: "Controller 1<p>
                     Production <?php echo $SumOfSUP_AC_TODAY_1; ?> kWh<br>
                     Energy <?php echo $SumOfAC_P_1; ?> kW<br>",
                     },
           {                
           key: "2", 
           toolTip: "Controller 2<p>
                     Production <?php echo $SumOfAC_TODAY_2; ?> kWh<br>
                     Energy <?php echo $SumOfAC_P_2; ?> kW<br>",
                     },
           {                
           key: "3", 
           toolTip: "Controller 3<p>
                     Production <?php echo $SumOfSUP_AC_TODAY_3; ?> kWh<br>
                     Energy <?php echo $SumOfAC_P_3; ?> kW<br>",
                     }

           etc etc...
```

Comment: The PHP will run on your server before it is sent to the browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, however you cannot have newlines in the JavaScript.

In modern browsers you can use the backtick instead of quotes

```
toolTip: `Controller 1<p>
          Production <?php echo $SumOfSUP_AC_TODAY_1; ?> kWh<br>
          Energy <?php echo $SumOfAC_P_1; ?> kW<br>`
```

but to be compatible, use \n or nothing instead:

```
toolTip: "Controller 1<p>\nProduction <?php echo $SumOfSUP_AC_TODAY_1; ?> kWh<br>\nEnergy <?php echo $SumOfAC_P_1; ?> kW<br>"
```

You can also generate the strings in the PHP:

[How to handle newlines in Javascript? (from PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270665/how-to-handle-newlines-in-javascript-from-php)

Comment: That's good to know regarding single lines in java. Do you know how to reference the java variable inside the php chevrons?  `for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    toolTip: "Controller i<p>\nProduction <?php echo $SumOfSUP_AC_TODAY_i; ?> kWh<br>\nEnergy <?php echo $SumOfAC_P_i; ?> kW<br>"
}`