# Laravel Blade, set textarea multi-line value with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I faced a problem with laravel blade template with javascript.

I have textarea and cancel button that return the textarea value to it's original value. But when the original value have multi-line, there error in script, because the blade print the value into the new line not \n in value.

Blade syntax:

`$('#my-textarea').val('{{ $oldValue }}');`

In html page source:

`$('#my-textarea').val('old 
value 
with
multiline');`

That one will cause error syntax in javascript
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Expected result:

`$('#my-textarea').val('old\nvalue\nwith\nmultiline');`

The question is, how can i print the value without being converted to actual new line but char `\n`?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270709/3226121)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just setting the contents of the textarea in HTML?  `<textarea>{{ $oldValue }}</textarea>`

Comment: @ljubadr thanks for the link, but i'm looking for "blade way" first, maybe i will use that one after give up on blade solution.

Comment: @Devon yah, i used that one too, but i need to set value back to old value using javascript after user edit the textarea.

Comment: Not sure there is a "blade" solution to this.  Add your own helper function to handle it based on the linked code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in your blade if you have installed `"laravelcollective/html"` package:

```
{{ 
    Form::hidden(
        'originalValue',
        $oldValue,
        array(
            'id'=>'originalValue'
        )
    ) 
}}
```

**Or** add following code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$oldValue}}" id="originalValue">
```

**And** your jQuery will be :

```
$('#my-textarea').val($('#originalValue').val());
```

Comment: I use your method at first, but i found another trick on the way. I am not sure it's safe to use this, but it's working for me:
```$('#my-textarea').val({!! json_encode($oldValue) !!});```
without quote inside ```val``` function