# using php string with line breaks as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was working on project in which I have to get some text from the database and display it in the text area. Working fine with no line breaks and tabs. but when a line breaks occurs it gives the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

My java script code is as :

```
<script type="application/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {


    document.getElementById('job_type').value = "<?php echo set_value('job_type') ?>";
    document.getElementById('job_cat').value = "<?php echo set_value('job_cat') ?>";

    if("<?php if(validation_errors() == false) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>"=="false")
    {
        $('#job_title').val("<?php echo $job[0]->job_title ?>");
        $('#job_type').val("<?php echo $job[0]->job_type ?>");
        $('#job_cat').val("<?php echo $job[0]->job_cat ?>");
        $('#salary').val("<?php echo $job[0]->salery ?>");
        $('#job_descp').text("<?php echo $job[0]->job_desc ?>");//error here



    }


    });


});


</script>
```

The text it was trying to set was

Error details are shown in images

[Debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd2r1.jpg)

I have tried using .html() and .val() too but nothing worked. How can I handle it.

Comment: you can try using the php function: htmlspecialchars

Comment: @Tom i tried isn't working also tried nl2br and str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270709/3004335

However, you can use `json_encode`

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('job_type').value = "<?php echo set_value('job_type') ?>";
    document.getElementById('job_cat').value = "<?php echo set_value('job_cat') ?>";

    if("<?php if(validation_errors() == false) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>"=="false")
    {
        $('#job_title').val(<?php echo json_encode($job[0]->job_title); ?>);
        $('#job_type').val(<?php echo json_encode($job[0]->job_type); ?>);
        $('#job_cat').val(<?php echo json_encode($job[0]->job_cat); ?>);
        $('#salary').val(<?php echo json_encode($job[0]->salery); ?>);
        $('#job_descp').text(<?php echo json_encode($job[0]->job_desc); ?>);//error here
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

You do however need to be careful about [cross site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

See here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet in particular rule #0

Answer (score 0):

Remove line break(CR LF) in `job[0]->job_desc`
like this:

```
$('#job_descp').text("<?php echo str_replace (array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '<br>', $job[0]->job_desc);?>");
```

Comment: the thing is that echoing text will convert it back to line break ...so isn't usable